# How to format hyperlink in clipboard for pasting into Evernote editor

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, clipboard, wysiwyg, evernote

I want to write a small Tampermonkey script which creates a hyperlink which can be inserted to a WYSIWYG editor, in my case - Evernote.

I managed to copy standard HTML markup to the clipboard in this format:

```html
<a href='https://www.foo.bar/'>my link</a>
```

However when pasting into the Evernote editor the markup will show up in plaintext, not as clickable hyperlink. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my shallow knowledge, the Evernote editor is not the WYSIWYG editor. It is an integrated text editor designed by Evernote developers that allows some (but not all) Markdown syntax, some HTML syntax, and some forms of media (PDF, audio and etc.) embedded in it.

Not sure on which platform you are using Evernote. Considering various possibilities, I will break down my reply as below.

---

#### Mobile device (tested on Android device)

Use Markdown link syntax:
`[my link](https://www.foo.bar/)`
and then hit `space`.

---

#### PC/Laptop (tested on Windows version)

The Markdown link syntax also works fine on PC.

But I prefer to use the shortcut `Ctrl + K`. To use it, just write some text, select the text (`my link` in your case), and hit the shortcut. This window will pop up [exampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01MiG.png).

Alternatively, right-click on selected text (`my link` in your case) with your cursor and choose the `Hyperlink` option then the `Add` option. This same window will pop up [exampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01MiG.png).